# Непрозрачный Statusbar при запуске нативного SplashScreen'a - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, splash-screen

Возможно ли убрать тень (затемнение) `StatusBar`'a? Перепробовал всё, в `styles.xml` прописывал атрибуты, в активити - условия, но ничего не помогает. Может кто сталкивался?
P.S. Использовал [этот](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) пакет, для создания `Splash`'a
[image: Скриншот с проблемой]

Comment: https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/issues/161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За наводку спасибо говорим [MiT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/261617/mit)!

Вот код, который помог исправить эту проблему:

```
package <ваше имя пакета>

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
}
```